# Trouble with flutter bloc ,cannot set favourites to a single item in list , when i try to select an item it will reflect all items in the list

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc, flutter-listview

here is my main screen ui page
to display notes in listview builder
here my issue is when i am trying to select an item to favourites (there is an icon for favourites) , it will select all list items to favourites , iam new to flutter bloc , i think here i am done something wrong on clicking the event, please help.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key,required this.title});
  final String title;
  List<NoteListModel>noteList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<NotesBloc,NotesState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if(state is NotesInitial)
              {
                return const Text('no text');
              }else if(state is NotesAddedState || state is NoteDeletedState
              || state is NotesFavouritesState)
              {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: state.noteList.length,
                    itemBuilder:(context,index){
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
                          leading:  Text(state.noteList[index].noteTitle.toString()),
                          subtitle:  Text(state.noteList[index].noteDetail.toString()),
                          trailing: SizedBox(
                            width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: state.favourites ?const Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.red,):
                                  const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if(state.favourites)
                                      {
                                        context.read<NotesBloc>().add(NoteFavouritesClicked(favourites: false,
                                            index: index));
                                      }else{
                                      context.read<NotesBloc>().add(NoteFavouritesClicked
                                        (favourites: true, index: index,));
                                    }
                                  },),
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print('deleted index:${index}');
                                    BlocProvider.of<NotesBloc>(context).add(
                                        NoteDeleteEvent(state.noteList[index]));
                                  },),

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
              return const Center(child: Text('error'),);
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton:  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed:(){
            Popup.showDialogPopup(context);
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          label: const Row(
            children: [
              Text('Add Note'),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Icon(Icons.add)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

here is my bloc class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import '../model/note_list_model.dart';
part 'notes_event.dart';
part 'notes_state.dart';

class NotesBloc extends Bloc<NotesEvent,NotesState> {
  List <NoteListModel>noteList = [];
  NotesBloc() : super(NotesInitial(noteList: [])) {
    on<NoteEvent>((event, emit) {
      noteList.add(event.note);
      emit(NotesAddedState(noteList:noteList));
    });

    on<NoteFavouritesClicked>((event, emit){
      if(event.index >= 0 && event.index < noteList.length)
        {
          noteList[event.index].favourites = event.favourites;
        }else{
        print('index out of bound');
      }
      emit(NotesFavouritesState(favourites: event.favourites, noteList:noteList));
    });

    on<NoteDeleteEvent>((event,emit){
       noteList.remove(event.noteDelete);
      emit(NoteDeletedState(noteList: noteList));
    });

    on<NoteUpdateEvent>((event,emit){
      noteList.add(event.updateNotes);
      emit(NoteUpdatedState(noteList: noteList));
    });
  }
}
```

here is my event class
add, delete , favourites.

```
part of 'notes_bloc.dart';

abstract class NotesEvent {
  const NotesEvent();
}

class NoteEvent  extends NotesEvent{
  NoteListModel note;
  NoteEvent(this.note);
}

class NoteDeleteEvent  extends NotesEvent{
  NoteListModel noteDelete;
  NoteDeleteEvent(this.noteDelete);
}
class NoteUpdateEvent extends NotesEvent{
  NoteListModel updateNotes;
  NoteUpdateEvent(this.updateNotes);
}

class NoteFavouritesClicked extends NotesEvent{
  int index;
  bool favourites;
  NoteFavouritesClicked({required this.favourites,required this.index});
}
```

here is my state class
for add note , delete note and favourites.

```
part of 'notes_bloc.dart';

  class NotesState {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  bool favourites;
  NotesState({required this.noteList,this.favourites = false});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList,favourites];
}
class NotesAddedState extends NotesState{
   List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NotesAddedState({required this.noteList}) : super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}
class NotesFavouritesState extends NotesState{
    bool favourites;
    NotesFavouritesState({this.favourites= false, required List<NoteListModel> noteList}) :
          super(noteList: noteList);
}
class NoteDeletedState extends NotesState{
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NoteDeletedState({required this.noteList}) : super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}
class NoteUpdatedState extends NotesState{
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NoteUpdatedState({required this.noteList}): super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}
class NotesInitial extends NotesState {
   NotesInitial({required super.noteList});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far i've gone through your code, i think the issue is occurring cause your `NotesBloc` class member `noteList` is non-static. So every time the new instance is being created.

So you make that list static as:

```
static List<NoteListModel> noteList = [];
```

And then you need to give it the values initially, like

```
NotesBloc.noteList = data; ;  /// your [DataList]
```

and you can use in your listView. as everyone sharing the same instance you no need to the emit the list with the states. you can just emit a state with no data and change will be reflect in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

From the code that I have seen you just need the following change in the UI every thing will work as expected.

```
IconButton(
                              icon: state.noteList[index].favourites == true
                                  ? const Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    )
                                  : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (state.favourites) {
                                  context.read<NotesBloc>().add(
                                      NoteFavouritesClicked(
                                          favourites: false, index: index));
                                } else {
                                  context
                                      .read<NotesBloc>()
                                      .add(NoteFavouritesClicked(
                                        favourites: true,
                                        index: index,
                                      ));
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

This above code is for the favorites button. please check the icon difference.

I have added the detailed answer if you want to run the app.

UI File

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bloc/todo_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'bloc/todo_bloc.dart';
import 'bloc/todo_event.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => NotesBloc(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ToDo App'),
      ),
      body: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList = [];

  TextEditingController noteTitleController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController noteDetailController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _showAlertDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          // <-- SEE HERE
          title: const Text(' Create new Note'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  controller: noteTitleController,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: noteDetailController,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Add note'),
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<NotesBloc>().add(NoteEvent(NoteListModel(
                    noteTitleController.text, noteDetailController.text)));

                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text('asdfasdf'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<NotesBloc, NotesState>(builder: (context, state) {
          print('This is the state ${state}');
          if (state is NotesInitial) {
            return const Text('no text');
          } else if (state is NotesAddedState ||
              state is NoteDeletedState ||
              state is NotesFavouritesState) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.noteList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
                      leading: Text(state.noteList[index].noteTitle.toString()),
                      subtitle:
                          Text(state.noteList[index].noteDetail.toString()),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: state.noteList[index].favourites == true
                                  ? const Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    )
                                  : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                              onPressed: () {
                                context
                                    .read<NotesBloc>()
                                    .add(NoteFavouritesClicked(index: index));
                              },
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('deleted index:${index}');
                                BlocProvider.of<NotesBloc>(context).add(
                                    NoteDeleteEvent(state.noteList[index]));
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
          return const Center(
            child: Text('error'),
          );
        }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () async {
            await _showAlertDialog();
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          label: const Row(
            children: [
              Text('Add Note'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Icon(Icons.add)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Created a bloc folder and added bloc event and state files in it please check I have made few changes.

Bloc file

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import '../bloc/todo_event.dart';
import '../bloc/todo_state.dart';

class NotesBloc extends Bloc<NotesEvent, NotesState> {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList = [];
  NotesBloc() : super(NotesInitial(noteList: [])) {
    on<NoteEvent>((event, emit) {
      noteList.add(event.note);
      emit(NotesAddedState(noteList: noteList));
    });

    on<NoteFavouritesClicked>((event, emit) {
      if (event.index >= 0 && event.index < noteList.length) {
        noteList[event.index].favourites = !noteList[event.index].favourites;
        noteList.forEach((element) {
          print("This is the list data :${element.favourites}");
          print('${element.noteTitle}');
        });
      } else {
        print('index out of bound');
      }
      emit(NotesFavouritesState(noteList: noteList));
    });

    on<NoteDeleteEvent>((event, emit) {
      noteList.remove(event.noteDelete);
      emit(NoteDeletedState(noteList: noteList));
    });

    on<NoteUpdateEvent>((event, emit) {
      noteList.add(event.updateNotes);
      emit(NoteUpdatedState(noteList: noteList));
    });
    emit(NotesInitial(noteList: []));
  }
}
```

Event file

```
import '../bloc/todo_state.dart';

abstract class NotesEvent {
  const NotesEvent();
}

class NoteEvent extends NotesEvent {
  NoteListModel note;
  NoteEvent(this.note);
}

class NoteDeleteEvent extends NotesEvent {
  NoteListModel noteDelete;
  NoteDeleteEvent(this.noteDelete);
}

class NoteUpdateEvent extends NotesEvent {
  NoteListModel updateNotes;
  NoteUpdateEvent(this.updateNotes);
}

class NoteFavouritesClicked extends NotesEvent {
  int index;

  NoteFavouritesClicked({required this.index});
}
```

State file

```
class NotesState {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  bool favourites;
  NotesState({required this.noteList, this.favourites = false});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList, favourites];
}

class NotesAddedState extends NotesState {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NotesAddedState({required this.noteList}) : super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}

class NotesFavouritesState extends NotesState {
  bool favourites;
  NotesFavouritesState(
      {this.favourites = false, required List<NoteListModel> noteList})
      : super(noteList: noteList);
}

class NoteDeletedState extends NotesState {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NoteDeletedState({required this.noteList}) : super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}

class NoteUpdatedState extends NotesState {
  List<NoteListModel> noteList;
  NoteUpdatedState({required this.noteList}) : super(noteList: noteList);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [noteList];
}

class NotesInitial extends NotesState {
  NotesInitial({required super.noteList});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class NoteListModel {
  String noteTitle;

  bool favourites;
  String noteDetail;

  NoteListModel(this.noteTitle, this.noteDetail, {this.favourites = false});
}
```

Comment: thanks@Sagar Acharya it works , but the on the first tap it doesn't change, it changes only when we click again

Comment: Please check the code i have made the changes.